# How to display tab Navigation in Stack screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am very new to React Native and I am currently implementing my navigation using the React Navigation docs. I am trying to have my Tab Navigators displayed on my stack screens but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I have been on this for a couple of hours with no solution. This is how my Tab Navigator is currently structured:

```
const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.ui.primary,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.ui.info,
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontWeight: Platform.OS === "ios" ? "600" : "500",
          fontSize: 15,
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          return <TabBarIcon route={route} focused={focused} />;
        },
        tabBarBadgeStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#22358e",
          color: "#fff",
          top: 0,
        },
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={CartsScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarBadge: 4 }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={FavoritesScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarBadge: 2 }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Account"
        component={Account}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={Menu}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Below is how I structured the Stack screen using the docs:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={TabNavigator}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="Products" component={ProductsScreen} />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Also, worthy of mentioning is that I'm using Typescript. So I have the Tab and Stack Navigators params typed:

```
export type TabStackParamsList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Account: undefined;
  Cart: undefined;
  Favorites: undefined;
  Menu: undefined;
};

export type RootStackParamsList = {
  Main: undefined;
  Products: { customer: CustomerItemType };
};
```

Currently, I can't get my Tabs to display on my Products Stack screen. I want this to appear on a couple of other stack screens. I will appreciate if someone could help point to what I'm doing wrong as it's my first time working with React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this and works.

take a look on this link:

https://github.com/itzpradip/react-navigation-v6-mix/blob/master/src/navigation/TabNavigator.js

there a video on youtube too. Maybe this can help you.